is Vov of a nMos always VGS - Vt?

Looking at this graph from Analog Circuit Design Discrete and Integrated by Sergio Franco, is it always true that Vov = VGS - Vt? or is this only true at pinchoff point?

The \$V_{OV}\$ given here is a definition, not a measurement. \$V_{OV}\$ is always equal to \$V_{GS}-V_t\$ by definition.
